# Plot an array of 3D points, while distinguishing a subset of them

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

This must be rather elementary, but what are my options for the presentation of this
array of (by way of example) fifty-three 3d points? I'd like to get some sense of the region defined by the points.

Also, what if I have a subset of the (53) points that I want to mark as "special" in some way? (I presume I should put those points in a second (smaller) array, to further proceed. I, now, give a subarray of 39 of the 53 points at the very end.)

```
{{7/22, 7/66, 197/1106}, {7/22, 123/3058, 39/281}, {104/347, 139/1041,
   38/337}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), -(2/33) (-5 + Sqrt[3]), 19/
  996}, {569/1915, 148/1395, 29/526}, {201/2540, 67/2540, 32/
  129}, {10856/33067, 3785/33067, 90/3347}, {4955/15921, 1744/13705, 
  65/847}, {5890/20091, 1219/8677, 97/732}, {4421/14324, 1631/12272, 
  17/230}, {155/669, 751/3944, 19/222}, {4419/14324, 249/2110, 83/
  599}, {15018/46267, 635/5779, 37/527}, {20910/66829, 6970/66829, 53/
  540}, {7674/26777, 17/4279, 1/8}, {17266/
  52867, (-3207 + 46 Sqrt[113314])/158601, 110/589}, {17293/52867, 
  232/2965, 44/623}, {97/1015, -((8 (-236 + Sqrt[34338]))/3045), 99/
  401}, {4481/15060, (7 (-231 + 2 Sqrt[73007]))/15060, 41/308}, {7/22,
   22082/178399, 89/1585}, {13571/42948, 1814/16413, 69/574}, {29370/
  95429, 437/3964, 24/559}, {7/22, 7/66, 547/
  5506}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 9/925, 22/411}, {2950/13371, 7471/
  40113, 29/916}, {11216/36805, 11216/110415, 29/259}, {4012/14707, 
  246/1669, 43/709}, {33285/104963, 291/2743, 19/277}, {10959/36805, 
  4594/31855, 67/1037}, {33160/104963, 103/1046, 21/179}, {35293/
  114496, 21955/171744, 9/224}, {8859/28624, 1661/12711, 11/
  963}, {11361/40148, 3787/40148, 22/233}, {2915/10037, 4207/30111, 
  65/696}, {7/22, 9374/79267, 26/453}, {26197/79267, 26197/237801, 97/
  2961}, {38303/124029, 68/1115, 81/497}, {4385/14497, 2693/20101, 41/
  703}, {7/22, 9321/85867, 41/600}, {39070/124029, 2091/16534, 10/
  659}, {4376/17379, 179/1239, 8/321}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 953/
  4988, 8/301}, {42224/133563, 42224/400689, 8/55}, {1589/6238, 510/
  3119, 4/793}, {7158/23417, 6337/48443, 48/679}, {41378/133563, 
  50807/400689, 25/358}, {14028/44521, (-7311 + 4 Sqrt[31578646])/
  133563, 38/587}, {13659/46834, 9758/70251, 53/693}, {31876/99067, 
  1589/13093, 61/2487}, {14203/
  50177, -((4 (-44501 + Sqrt[1896143109]))/150531), 44/419}, {32551/
  99067, 167/2379, 1/12}, {44715/143096, 26833/214644, 7/101}, {14926/
  50177, 85/5591, 71/471}}
```

The points {Q1,Q2,Q3} all lie within the region Q1 > 0 && Q2 > 0 && Q3 > 0 && Q1 + 3 Q2 + 2 Q3 < 1.

The 39-point subset of the 53 points I want  to distinguish is

```
{{7/22, 123/3058, 39/
  281}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), -(2/33) (-5 + Sqrt[3]), 19/996}, {569/
  1915, 148/1395, 29/526}, {10856/33067, 3785/33067, 90/3347}, {4955/
  15921, 1744/13705, 65/847}, {4421/14324, 1631/12272, 17/
  230}, {15018/46267, 635/5779, 37/527}, {20910/66829, 6970/66829, 53/
  540}, {17293/52867, 232/2965, 44/623}, {7/22, 22082/178399, 89/
  1585}, {29370/95429, 437/3964, 24/559}, {7/22, 7/66, 547/
  5506}, {2950/13371, 7471/40113, 29/916}, {11216/36805, 11216/110415,
   29/259}, {4012/14707, 246/1669, 43/709}, {33285/104963, 291/2743, 
  19/277}, {10959/36805, 4594/31855, 67/1037}, {33160/104963, 103/
  1046, 21/179}, {35293/114496, 21955/171744, 9/224}, {8859/28624, 
  1661/12711, 11/963}, {11361/40148, 3787/40148, 22/233}, {2915/10037,
   4207/30111, 65/696}, {7/22, 9374/79267, 26/453}, {26197/79267, 
  26197/237801, 97/2961}, {38303/124029, 68/1115, 81/497}, {4385/
  14497, 2693/20101, 41/703}, {7/22, 9321/85867, 41/600}, {39070/
  124029, 2091/16534, 10/659}, {4376/17379, 179/1239, 8/
  321}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 953/4988, 8/301}, {1589/6238, 510/3119,
   4/793}, {7158/23417, 6337/48443, 48/679}, {41378/133563, 50807/
  400689, 25/358}, {14028/44521, (-7311 + 4 Sqrt[31578646])/133563, 
  38/587}, {13659/46834, 9758/70251, 53/693}, {31876/99067, 1589/
  13093, 61/2487}, {14203/
  50177, -((4 (-44501 + Sqrt[1896143109]))/150531), 44/419}, {32551/
  99067, 167/2379, 1/12}, {44715/143096, 26833/214644, 7/101}}
```

Comment: See [ListPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html).

Comment: Check out examples in [ListPointPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html) and 3D examples in [Point](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html).

Comment: Please as *minimal* questions.  You do not need to fill a page with useless and irrelevant fractions.  Moreover, learn how to use proper formatting, so others can cut and paste your data points.

Comment: Well, I don't understand what's meant by minimal questions. (Your first period does not end a properly-structured sentence.) Also, I see no problem with cutting-and-pasting, which I just easily performed. Also, I think the  "useless and irrelevant fractions" comment is rather overboard. I anticipated as part of an answer, someone might  be happy/pleased to present specific graphs. I see--Mr. Stork--you have a high reputation, but you strike me (at least from this forceful comment of yours), as something of a martinet! (Wow, I may be banned for life from stackexchange.)

Comment: Oh, I only now see that the penultimate comment (of David G. Stork) was meant to begin "Please as[K} minimal questions".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Graphics3D[Map[Point,yourlist],Axes->True]
```

Then you can place your mouse inside the box, press and hold the left mouse button and drag the box around to see it from different directions.

Comment: You do not need to `Map`, this will do: `Graphics3D[Point[yourlist], Axes -> True]`.

Comment: Interesting! I get two clearly distinct sets of points. What if I have a subset of the (53) points that I want to mark as "special" in some way? (I  presume I should put those points in a second (smaller) array, to further proceed.)

Comment: Try `Show[
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1,0,0],Point[yourlist1]}],
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0,1,0],Point[yourlist2]}]]`

Comment: Looks great, Bill ! Can I label the three axes--I couldn't seem to do so immediately? I get red and green points. Which should correspond to "yourlist1" and which to "yourlist2".

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the comment of Bill, I used his indicated command

```
Show[ Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1,0,0],Point[yourlist1]}], Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0,1,0],Point[yourlist2]}]]
```

on expanded lists of length 7,566 (corresponding to "two-qutrit entangled states") and 5,373 (corresponding to the subset of "two-qutrit bound-entangled states"), and got the image

[image]

But, I'm not sure now which color corresponds to which list--and I'd like to also add AxesLabels. (I think, just based on subject matter considerations, that red corresponds to the second list--but please correct me, if I am mistaken.)

A "toy" example

```
f8 = Array[1, 100]; f9 = f8; Do[f8[[i]] = {2 i, 2 i, 2 i}; f9[[i]] = {i, i, i}, {i, 1, 100}]; Show[Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Point[f8]}],Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], Point[f9]}]]
```

convinced me that the green does, in fact, correspond to the second list. But I still desire AxesLabel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The full data is

```
data = {{7/22, 7/66, 197/1106}, {7/22, 123/3058, 39/281}, {104/347, 
    139/1041, 38/337}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), -(2/33) (-5 + Sqrt[3]), 
    19/996}, {569/1915, 148/1395, 29/526}, {201/2540, 67/2540, 
    32/129}, {10856/33067, 3785/33067, 90/3347}, {4955/15921, 
    1744/13705, 65/847}, {5890/20091, 1219/8677, 97/732}, {4421/14324,
     1631/12272, 17/230}, {155/669, 751/3944, 19/222}, {4419/14324, 
    249/2110, 83/599}, {15018/46267, 635/5779, 37/527}, {20910/66829, 
    6970/66829, 53/540}, {7674/26777, 17/4279, 
    1/8}, {17266/52867, (-3207 + 46 Sqrt[113314])/158601, 
    110/589}, {17293/52867, 232/2965, 
    44/623}, {97/1015, -((8 (-236 + Sqrt[34338]))/3045), 
    99/401}, {4481/15060, (7 (-231 + 2 Sqrt[73007]))/15060, 
    41/308}, {7/22, 22082/178399, 89/1585}, {13571/42948, 1814/16413, 
    69/574}, {29370/95429, 437/3964, 24/559}, {7/22, 7/66, 
    547/5506}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 9/925, 22/411}, {2950/13371, 
    7471/40113, 29/916}, {11216/36805, 11216/110415, 
    29/259}, {4012/14707, 246/1669, 43/709}, {33285/104963, 291/2743, 
    19/277}, {10959/36805, 4594/31855, 67/1037}, {33160/104963, 
    103/1046, 21/179}, {35293/114496, 21955/171744, 
    9/224}, {8859/28624, 1661/12711, 11/963}, {11361/40148, 
    3787/40148, 22/233}, {2915/10037, 4207/30111, 65/696}, {7/22, 
    9374/79267, 26/453}, {26197/79267, 26197/237801, 
    97/2961}, {38303/124029, 68/1115, 81/497}, {4385/14497, 
    2693/20101, 41/703}, {7/22, 9321/85867, 41/600}, {39070/124029, 
    2091/16534, 10/659}, {4376/17379, 179/1239, 
    8/321}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 953/4988, 8/301}, {42224/133563, 
    42224/400689, 8/55}, {1589/6238, 510/3119, 4/793}, {7158/23417, 
    6337/48443, 48/679}, {41378/133563, 50807/400689, 
    25/358}, {14028/44521, (-7311 + 4 Sqrt[31578646])/133563, 
    38/587}, {13659/46834, 9758/70251, 53/693}, {31876/99067, 
    1589/13093, 
    61/2487}, {14203/50177, -((4 (-44501 + Sqrt[1896143109]))/150531),
     44/419}, {32551/99067, 167/2379, 1/12}, {44715/143096, 
    26833/214644, 7/101}, {14926/50177, 85/5591, 71/471}};
```

The special data is

```
special = {{7/22, 123/3058, 
    39/281}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), -(2/33) (-5 + Sqrt[3]), 
    19/996}, {569/1915, 148/1395, 29/526}, {10856/33067, 3785/33067, 
    90/3347}, {4955/15921, 1744/13705, 65/847}, {4421/14324, 
    1631/12272, 17/230}, {15018/46267, 635/5779, 
    37/527}, {20910/66829, 6970/66829, 53/540}, {17293/52867, 
    232/2965, 44/623}, {7/22, 22082/178399, 89/1585}, {29370/95429, 
    437/3964, 24/559}, {7/22, 7/66, 547/5506}, {2950/13371, 
    7471/40113, 29/916}, {11216/36805, 11216/110415, 
    29/259}, {4012/14707, 246/1669, 43/709}, {33285/104963, 291/2743, 
    19/277}, {10959/36805, 4594/31855, 67/1037}, {33160/104963, 
    103/1046, 21/179}, {35293/114496, 21955/171744, 
    9/224}, {8859/28624, 1661/12711, 11/963}, {11361/40148, 
    3787/40148, 22/233}, {2915/10037, 4207/30111, 65/696}, {7/22, 
    9374/79267, 26/453}, {26197/79267, 26197/237801, 
    97/2961}, {38303/124029, 68/1115, 81/497}, {4385/14497, 
    2693/20101, 41/703}, {7/22, 9321/85867, 41/600}, {39070/124029, 
    2091/16534, 10/659}, {4376/17379, 179/1239, 
    8/321}, {1/22 (1 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 953/4988, 8/301}, {1589/6238, 
    510/3119, 4/793}, {7158/23417, 6337/48443, 48/679}, {41378/133563,
     50807/400689, 
    25/358}, {14028/44521, (-7311 + 4 Sqrt[31578646])/133563, 
    38/587}, {13659/46834, 9758/70251, 53/693}, {31876/99067, 
    1589/13093, 
    61/2487}, {14203/50177, -((4 (-44501 + Sqrt[1896143109]))/150531),
     44/419}, {32551/99067, 167/2379, 1/12}, {44715/143096, 
    26833/214644, 7/101}};
```

The non-special, i.e., other data is

```
other = Complement[data, special];
```

Plotting

```
Show[
 ListPlot3D[{special, other},
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Blue], Opacity[0.5, Orange]},
  PlotLegends -> {"special", "other"}],
 ListPointPlot3D[{special, other},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Orange}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z})]
```

[image]